# getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(resource) return null in java 11

Tags: java, java-8, openshift, java-11

I am migrating spring boot java project from openshift-jdk-8 to openshift-jdk-11. In java-11 below line always returning null when project is deployed as docker image in openshift cloud environment. The same code is working fine while running in windows/local environment.

```
getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("mapper/myfile.xml")
```

Loading the file from bean-io dependency

```
implementation("org.beanio:beanio:2.1.0")
```

I have file under below location inside this jar.

```
BOOT-INF
 --classes
    --mapper/myfile.xml
```

Getting below error

```
   2021-03-10T10:39:27.555-05:00,severity=ERROR,thread=ForkJoinPool-10-worker-3,
org.beanio.BeanIOConfigurationException: BeanIO mapping file 'mapper/myfile.xml' not found on classpath
    at org.beanio.StreamFactory.loadResource(StreamFactory.java:213) ~[beanio-2.1.0.jar!/:2.1.0]
    at org.beanio.StreamFactory.loadResource(StreamFactory.java:198) ~[beanio-2.1.0.jar!/:2.1.0]
    at com.payment.ene.xerox.domain.SortIndexHandler.<init>(SortIndexHandler.java:51) ~[gen-copy-dmz.120.jar!/:?]
    at com.payment.ene.xerox.domain.exstream.PrintFlowOrchestratorImpl.lambda$printPrep$0(CopyFlowOrchestratorImpl.java:100) ~[gen-copy-dmz.120.jar!/:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1448) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183) [?:?]
```

Any suggestion to resolve this issue

Comment: It’s not helpful to have two fundamental changes in the environment, i.e. “windows/local” vs “docker image in openshift cloud” and “java 8” vs “java 11”. You surely can test the code with java 11 and java 8 in your local Windows environment to find out, whether the issue is connected to the java version or not.

Answer (score 1):

You could try java.nio:

```
new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(absoluteFilePath)));
```